# How to check whether a large file is uploaded correctly

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm using [Jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload files onto php server. I would like to modify the uploader such that I can check whether the uploaded file is the same as the local file.

My current idea is to use checksum to check whether the files are identical. However, I need to support large files (1GB). As I understand, we cannot load 1GB file using `HTML5 File API` for the hashing function.

The way `Jquery file upload` handles large file is to load part of the file and send it. So is there any way to do checksum when files are chopped into pieces? Or there are any other ways to check whether a file is correctly uploaded?

Comment: PHP does it by itself, no?

Comment: jquery file uploader upload large files using chunks. PHP MAY check each chunk is correctly uploaded, but not the whole file?

Comment: btw is that PHP will check whether each chunk is correctly uploaded?

Comment: [`UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) ?

Comment: @OscarTang I don't think so ... should be a function of TCP but I've seen plenty of corrupt files transferred via TCP it's its by no means fullproof in the real world

Comment: `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL is given when the mime boundary is not found after the file data. A possibly cause for this is that the upload was cancelled by the user (pressed ESC, etc).`

This is not checking the correctness of the file

Comment: @CORRUPT that will tell you if the the file is truncated, not if it is currupt

Comment: You need some means of fingerprinting the file on the client side that is reliably reproducible on the server

Comment: @Orangepill I am not worrying of the corruption of the packet. Instead, I'm worrying wrong chunk uploaded. So, files with the length same as the local one is transferred but the content is incorrect.

Comment: @Orangepill yea thats why i'm finding a way to fingerprint the file. Checksum seems not work?

Comment: Pass `MD5` from client in headers or as url parameter. Compute `MD5` of file on server. Comapre them.

Comment: looks like there is a js implementation of md5 you could use http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/

Comment: doing some kind of CRC would work pretty reliably... MD5 would offer less chance of a false positive though

Comment: plus calculating the md5 hash for a  1+ GB file may very well kill the  the browser

Comment: @Orangepill As stated in the question, it seems that I cannot use MD5 too. It is because I cannot load the whole file (1GB) into memory for MD5 encoding.

Comment: CRC check the chunks individual... 32 bit CRC is here... http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-crc32.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the file size, since HTTP connections won't mess up chunk order nor send wrong bytes. The real corruption will be in truncated files.

Comment: Q: doesn't that depend on OS? The above is what I would expect on all *nixes but windows?